# A piecewise model with exponential and linear regressions in r

Tags: r, linear-regression, exponential, piecewise

I am trying to fit a regression model to my data. An exponential model fits the first part of the data. But the best fit for the second part is linear regression. I am looking for a function in r that can develop a piecewise regression model and find the optimum breakpoint between two regressions. I read about the segmented function in r but saw that it only works when the two regression models around the breakpoint are the same. I am looking for a function that works when one exponential and one linear model are used in the piecewise regression. A screenshot of the data points and initial exponential and linear regression models are provided here.

I considered that the breakpoint is 100 on the horizontal axes and divided my data into two parts. This figure shows the data and the fitted model when I fit a piecewise regression to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKGP6.png)
This figure shows the data and the fitted model when I fit only an exponential regression to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXbVa.png)

Regards,
Reza.

Comment: The entire trend looks exponential to me. If you want help, including a `dput` of your data is better than an image of it. The latter is exponentially less likely to get help *.*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question and added the figure of the fitted regression when only exponential regression is used. It does not fit well when I only use exponential regression. I was wondering to know what you mean by dput. Do you mean to add my code or my data?

Comment: I don't know if there is a package for it, but you might be able to do this by creating your own code. See iterative searching method [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/08/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset to work with, such as using the `dput` command. Here is a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example